# Books on algebraic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am interested in learning about algebraic surfaces (e.g. their classification in characteristic 0), and I was wondering whether any knowledgeable people would be so kind as to give their thoughts about the character of the various books that are available. The options seem to include the books by Beauville, Badescu, and Barth-Hulek-Peters-van de Ven, the chapters by Reid, and the Shafarevich seminar journal issue. There is also a survey by Iskovskikh & Shafarevich in the Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences.

Comment: Barth, et al is beautiful but does things from an analytic viewpoint that you may not be comfortable with; it depends on your background. I think Beauville is a really good choice, personally.

Comment: Dear Marius, I presume the answer is "yes", but just in case: have you worked through Hartshorne Ch. V?  This discusses (but doesn't prove) the classification, but has much useful preliminary material.  Regards,